# Is there a way to set charset using the web.config in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding

Recently I came across a situation where, while using a double-byte language, I had to enter the charset as a metatag.

Previously I had thought that the globalization tag in the web.config would handle the page charset, but this seems not to be the case.

Is there a way to set charset in the web.config or a way to set the charset of an entire web site without having to enter the metatag on every page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't setting the responseEncoding in the globalization element in the web.config like this, work?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding=""
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="de-DE"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Otherwise, use a basepage and set the charset in there, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: That is what I thought, but in this particular case the title tag didn't render in the correct encoding.  Only by adding the meta tag did the title come out correctly.

Comment: Just tried this, but I'm not seeing a response header with or without the `<globalization>` element in Web.config.

Comment: Why did you revise your original post to change `<responseEncoding="utf-8">` to `<responseEncoding="">`? This contradicts the MSDN article on [globalization via Web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx) that you originally referenced. I don't see any mention in that article about a default value for `responseEncoding`.